# How to export CMake targets with dependant include directories?

Tags: cmake, target

I am trying to export CMake targets such that they also include the public include directories of dependant targets.

Let there be three separate but depending CMake projects:

1. `foobar_result` defines a data type and methods for this datatype in `result.hpp`
2. `foobar_interface` defines a header-only abstract class in `foobar_interface.hpp` which uses the datatype defined in `foobar_result` (`#include <result.hpp>`)
3. `foobar_implA` is an implementation (`foobar_implA.cpp`, `foobar_implA.hpp`) of the abstract class in `foobar_interface` (`#include <foobar_interface.hpp>`), and hence indirectly depends on the datatype definition (it `#include <result.hpp>` via `#include <foobar_interface.hpp>`)

What I want to achieve is that when `foobar_implA` is `find_package(foobar_interface)`, it should automatically populate the include directories and libraries with the dependencies of `foobar_interface` so that `foobar_implA` does not have to discover `foobar_result`'s include directories manually.

---

So far, I tried to specify the three CMake projects as follows.

#### 1. `foobar_result`

`foobar_result` defines a standard library with headers:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(foobar_result)

include(GNUInstallDirs)

add_library(result SHARED src/result.cpp)

target_include_directories(result PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:$<INSTALL_PREFIX>/${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}>
)

install(EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}
    DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME}/cmake
    FILE ${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake
)

install(TARGETS result EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME})

install(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
    FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.hpp"
)
```

The exported `foobar_resultConfig.cmake`:

```
add_library(result SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(result PROPERTIES
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/include"
)
```

and `foobar_resultConfig-noconfig.cmake`:

```
set_target_properties(result PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LOCATION_NOCONFIG "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/libresult.so"
  IMPORTED_SONAME_NOCONFIG "libresult.so"
  )
```

correctly define the includes and libraries.

#### 2. `foobar_interface`

The interface uses the `result` library:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(foobar_interface)

include(GNUInstallDirs)

find_package(foobar_result REQUIRED)

add_library(foobar_interface INTERFACE)
target_link_libraries(foobar_interface INTERFACE result)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:$<INSTALL_PREFIX>/${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}>
)

install(EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}
    DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME}/cmake
    FILE ${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake
)

install(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
    FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.hpp"
)

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME})
```

Now, although the interface `foobar_interface` links the `result` library, the exported configuration:

```
add_library(foobar_interface INTERFACE IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(foobar_interface PROPERTIES
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/include"
  INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES "result"
)
```

only depends on the `result` library, but not its include directories. **`foobar_interface` only exports its own `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`, but not those of its dependency `foobar_result`.**

#### 3. `foobar_implA`

The implementation of the interface depends only on `foobar_implA`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(foobar_implA)

include(GNUInstallDirs)

find_package(foobar_interface REQUIRED)

add_library(foobar_implA SHARED src/foobar_implA.cpp)
target_link_libraries(foobar_implA PUBLIC foobar_interface)

target_include_directories(foobar_implA PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:$<INSTALL_PREFIX>/${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}>
)

install(EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}
    DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME}/cmake
    FILE ${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake
)

install(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
    FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.hpp"
)

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME})
```

fails with:

```
In file included from [...]/src/foobar_implA/include/foobar_implA.hpp:3,
                 from [...]/src/foobar_implA/src/foobar_implA.cpp:1:
[...]/install/foobar_interface/include/foobar_interface.hpp:3:10: fatal error: result.hpp: No such file or directory
    3 | #include <result.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

because `find_package(foobar_interface)` will not populate the include directories with the one defined in `foobar_result`.

I can only work around this issue by manually including `foobar_result` again:

```
find_package(foobar_result REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(foobar_implA PUBLIC result)
```

but this is obviously not what I want, as this would not scale well when the dependencies in `foobar_interface` increase.

---

I am using [colcon](http://colcon.readthedocs.io) to separate the build and install spaces for all three projects. This way, all projects have to properly export and import their include and link directories. Installing all projects in the same prefix would also circumvent this problem, as `foobar_interface` include directories would also contain headers from `foobar_result`.

Comment: Actually, the call `target_link_libraries(foobar_interface INTERFACE result)` is added to the `foobar_interface` config script. But `find_package(foobar_interface REQUIRED)` is not. You need to add this call explicitly into the config script in form of `find_dependency`. See [their manual](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html) about proper way for creating of the config script (this script shouldn't be created directly with `install(EXPORT)`).

Comment: See also [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62519433/3440745), which creates the config script in a proper way (via `configure_package_config_file`) but still misses `find_dependency`.